# Convert IEnumerable to type that implements IEnumerable

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

**GIVEN:**

If you have the values:

1. `Type type`
2. `IEnumerable enumerable`

And the following conditions are met:

1. `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)`
2. `enumerable.All(element => element.GetType() == type.GetElementType())`

**GENERAL QUESTION:**

Is it possible to create an instance of `type` via reflection that contains all of the elements of `enumerable`?

**BACKGROUND:**

Most of the types in `System.Collections` have a constructor like `Example(ICollection)`, and if `type` has a constructor like that it is simple and straightforward to do `Activator.CreateInstance(type, enumerable)`.  For types like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` though, it is not that simple.  The only solution I have thought of looks like this:

```
var dictionary = (IDictionary) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var elementType = enumerable.First().GetType();
var key = elementType.GetProperty("Key");
var value = elementType.GetProperty("Value");

foreach (var element in enumerable)
{
   dictionary.Add(key.GetValue(element), value.GetValue(element));
}
```

I would be more willing to accept this solution of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`implemented an interface which contained the properties `Key` and `Value` so you could say:

```
var keyValuePair = (IKeyValuePair) element;
dictionary.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
```

rather than relying on reflection to get the aforementioned property values.

This solution would only work for types within `System.Collections` or custom types that strongly adhere to the definitions of said types.

**SPECIFIC QUESTION:**

Is there a more elegant way of converting `enumerable` to the type of `type`that also could account for edge cases like `MyCollection : ICollection`, where the type definition is not known to us?

UPDATE:

Here is an example:

```
var original = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
   //values
};

var type = original.GetType();
var enumerable = original.AsEnumerable();

var copy = (Dictionary<int, string>) DoSomeMagic(type, enumerable);

object DoSomeMagic(Type type, IEnumerable enumerable)
{
   //Add magic here
}
```

Comment: What is the enumerable in the dictionary case?

Comment: It would be IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.  I think I see what you are getting at, so to further clarify, enumerable is not a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> that has been cast down to IEnumerable.

Comment: I don't see it listed in the documentation, and manually creating an array of KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> and passing it into the constructor of Dictionary<TKey, TValue> has a compile error.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it possible to create an instance of type via reflection that contains all of the elements of enumerable?"?

Comment: I want the instance of type when enumerated to equal enumerable.

Comment: What does "I want the instance of type when enumerated to equal enumerable." mean? I'm really lost here. Can you explain using concrete types?

Comment: Can you talk us through why the input is a non-generic `IEnumerable` to start with?

Comment: I am trying to create my own serializer, and I am saving the elements of anything IEnumerable as a collection of  the serialized object references.

Comment: It seems to me that there's a reason that serializers generally disallow abstract/interface types. I.e. there is in fact _not_ any "elegant" way to address this problem generally. Taking the dictionary example: so, you've stored `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` in your serialized data. Since `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, which in turn implements `Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)`, there is in fact a direct line from the source data to an instantiated object. ...

Comment: ...But that could come from any implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or any implementation of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` (e.g. `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, for that matter. The consumer of the data after deserialization almost certainly will care about the difference. But if you don't include in the serialized data the concrete type that data should be deserialized into, the consumer won't be ensured of getting the right type.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few reasons left to use good old [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
System.Array ConvertUnknownIEnumerableToArray(IEnumerable ienumerable, Type type)
{
    var list = new ArrayList();
    foreach (var i in ienumerable) list.Add(i);
    return list.ToArray(type);
}
```

The above creates a strongly typed array (named `array`) of the concrete objects contained in any enumerable named `ienumerable`.  An array, of course, implements `ICollection`.

This technique allows you to avoid Reflection figuring out which generic MethodInfo to create and invoke to create the array. The framework does it for you.